# Join tables based on best matching collection of multiple foreign keys, each of which are nullable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a tSQL query that is able to join two tables into the data I need. Each of the two tables have the same set of 3 foreign keys to other tables (e.g. tables {x, y, z}). On *table1* the foreign keys are non-null and *table2* all three keys are nullable.

**Example Table Schema:**

Table 1 **[**`id, fk_x (non null), fk_y (non null), fk_z (non null), table1_data`**]**

Table 2 **[**`id, fk_x (null),     fk_y (null),     fk_z (null),     table2_data`**]**

I need to join each row in table1 with exactly one row in table 2 that best matches the keys in table1. By best match I mean the following.

1. All non-null keys in table2 must match the keys in table1.
2. Null keys in table2 are matches for any key value in table1.
3. The row that contains the most amount of matching keys wins.
4. Rows with the same number of matching keys will weight the keys where `fk_x > fk_y > fk_z` to determine the tie breaker.

Note: There is a unique constraint on table2 guaranteeing only 1 combination of the 3 keys exists in the table.

**Example**

```
[Table1]
+----+-----+-----+-----+------+
| id |fk_x |fk_y |fk_z | data |
+-----------------------------+
| 1  | 9   |  3  | 11  |  a   |
+-----------------------------+
| 2  | 9   |  4  |  2  |  b   |
+-----------------------------+
| 3  | 7   |  5  |  2  |  c   |
+-----------------------------+
| 4  | 7   |  6  |  2  |  d   |
+----+-----+-----+-----+------+

[Table2]
+----+-----+-----+-----+------+
| id |fk_x |fk_y |fk_z | data |
+-----------------------------+
| 10 | null| null| null|   A  |
+-----------------------------+
| 20 | null|  5  |  2  |   B  |
+-----------------------------+
| 30 | 7   |  5  | null|   C  |
+-----------------------------+
| 40 | 7   | null|  2  |   D  |
+----+-----+-----+-----+------+

[Results]
+----+-----+-----+-----+------+
| id |  t1_data  |  t2_data   |
+-----------------------------+
| 1  |    a      |     A      |
+-----------------------------+
| 2  |    b      |     A      |
+-----------------------------+
| 3  |    c      |     C      |
+-----------------------------+
| 4  |    d      |     D      |
+----+-----+-----+-----+------+
```

I have been having trouble trying to solve for requirements 3 & 4. If anyone can offer any tips or solutions to this I would greatly appreciate it.

*BTW: I'll be running the query on SQL Server 2014.*

Comment: Can you post the query you are trying with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply`:

```
select t1.*, t2.t2_data
from table1 t1 outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from table2 t2
      where (t2.fk_x is null or t2.fk_x = t1.fk_x) and
            (t2.fk_y is null or t2.fk_y = t1.fk_y) and
            (t2.fk_z is null or t2.fk_z = t1.fk_z)
      order by ( (case when t2.fk_x is not null then 4 else 0 end) +
                 (case when t2.fk_y is not null then 2 else 0 end) +
                 (case when t2.fk_z is not null then 1 else 0 end)
               ) desc
     ) t2;
```

The subquery finds all matching rows in `table2` according to your rules -- either `NULL` matches or exact matches.

The `order by` then orders by the number of exact matches, so the best matching row can be returned.

Comment: Thanks, this solution works for what I needed. I just had to modify the values for the case conditions to handle the key priority requirements. I modified the values to {4, 2, 1} for the keys {x, y, z} respectively. I'd mark this as the solution with those modifications.

Comment: @NickC . . . I see the tie-breaker requirement now.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

First with a `CTE` where you apply the conditions and then with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
with cte as (
  select t1.id, t1.data t1_data, t2.data t2_data,
    case when t1.fk_x = t2.fk_x then 100 else 0 end + 
    case when t1.fk_y = t2.fk_y then 10 else 0 end +
    case when t1.fk_z = t2.fk_Z then 1 else 0 end matchxyz
  from table1 t1 left join table2 t2
  on t1.fk_x = coalesce(t2.fk_x, t1.fk_x)
  and t1.fk_y = coalesce(t2.fk_y, t1.fk_y)
  and t1.fk_z = coalesce(t2.fk_z, t1.fk_z)
)

select c.id, c.t1_data, c.t2_data from cte c
where not exists (
  select 1 from cte 
  where id = c.id and t1_data = c.t1_data and matchxyz > c.matchxyz
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=de3f8f949dc8e1f06722a33ad9b48099):
Results:

```
> id | t1_data | t2_data
> -: | :------ | :------
>  1 | a       | A      
>  2 | b       | A      
>  3 | c       | C      
>  4 | d       | D
```